# converting a list to dataframe pandas

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe

Creating a list in a loop, my final list looks like below:

```
L [col1, col2, col3, col4 \
 0 N 225.0 12.0 03.0 B ,
   col1, col2, col3, col4 \
 0 W 223.0 12.0 01.0 M ,
   col1, col2, col3, col4 \
 0 X 203.0 11.0 04.0 P ]
```

Im trying to convert this to a pandas DataFrame?

Each row looks like a proper dataframe in itself:

```
L[0]  
col1 col2 col3 col4
N 225.0 12.0 03.0 B
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe need create 2d numpy array with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
L = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 
    'N 225.0', '12.0', '03.0', 'B' ,
   'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 
    'W 223.0', '12.0', '01.0', 'M' ,
   'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 
    'X 203.0', '11.0', '04.0', 'P' ]

a = np.array(L).reshape(-1, 8)[:, -4:]
print (a)
[['N 225.0' '12.0' '03.0' 'B']
 ['W 223.0' '12.0' '01.0' 'M']
 ['X 203.0' '11.0' '04.0' 'P']]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = L[:4])
print (df)
      col1  col2  col3 col4
0  N 225.0  12.0  03.0    B
1  W 223.0  12.0  01.0    M
2  X 203.0  11.0  04.0    P
```

**Explanation**:

First convert list to 1d numpy array:

```
print (np.array(L))
['col1' 'col2' 'col3' 'col4' 'N 225.0' '12.0' '03.0' 'B' 'col1' 'col2'
 'col3' 'col4' 'W 223.0' '12.0' '01.0' 'M' 'col1' 'col2' 'col3' 'col4'
 'X 203.0' '11.0' '04.0' 'P']
```

then [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to Nx8 nd array:

```
print (np.array(L).reshape(-1, 8))
[['col1' 'col2' 'col3' 'col4' 'N 225.0' '12.0' '03.0' 'B']
 ['col1' 'col2' 'col3' 'col4' 'W 223.0' '12.0' '01.0' 'M']
 ['col1' 'col2' 'col3' 'col4' 'X 203.0' '11.0' '04.0' 'P']]
```

And last select last 4 colums:

```
print (np.array(L).reshape(-1, 8)[:, -4:])
[['N 225.0' '12.0' '03.0' 'B']
 ['W 223.0' '12.0' '01.0' 'M']
 ['X 203.0' '11.0' '04.0' 'P']]
```

Comment: could you explain the solution?

Comment: @harold_noobie - Sure, but one thing, my list is same like your? Because `,` and `'` are mising in your data.

Comment: not working. I get a key error, while converting to array: np.array(L)

Comment: @harold_noobie - My list `L` is same like your? Or soemthing different?

Comment: My List has index as well, edited the original quest - That is why Im getting Key error while trying the np based solution.

Comment: @harold_noobie - I think I understand, how working `df = pd.concat(L, ignore_index=True)` ? Because it seems there is `list of DataFrames`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
L = ['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure']

#create new df 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})
print (df)
```

Comment: There are `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4` in data, so this is not possible use.

Comment: My list has columns aswell.